# Create a nested return model with Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, hapi.js

I'm using Knex.js to query a MySQL database in a Hapi.js route. The following code works but requires a nested query:

```
{
    path: '/recipes',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: (req, res) => {
        const getOperation = Knex.from('recipes')
        // .innerJoin('ingredients', 'recipes.guid', 'ingredients.recipe')
        .select()
        .orderBy('rating', 'desc')
        .limit(10)
        .then((recipes) => {
            if (!recipes || recipes.length === 0) {
                res({
                    error: true,
                    errMessage: 'no recipes found'
                });
            }

            const recipeGuids = recipes.map(recipe => recipe.guid);
            recipes.forEach(r => r.ingredients = []);
            const getOperation2 = Knex.from('ingredients')
                .whereIn('recipe', recipeGuids)
                .select()
                .then((ingredients) => {
                    recipes.forEach(r => {
                        ingredients.forEach(i => {
                            if (i.recipe === r.guid) {
                                r.ingredients.push(i);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    res({
                        count: recipes.length,
                        data: recipes
                    });
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a return model with Knex.js that has nested objects that match the parent's id/guid so that I don't have nested promises?

Comment: What about the DB performance? Isn't one query better than hitting the database with few queries for the same result, especially in large systems? 

Facing the same problem, solved by TransformSomeResponse() for each GET request at the client side to transform the obj into the required structure.  This sounds a bit ugly TBH in a large system. Therefore, I am considering ditching the Knex because it does not support producing nested responses like Mongoose (Do not have experience with sequelize).

Comment: The join query is almost sure to outperform the multiple subqueries or separate queries for constructing the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

With Knex, you can retrieve data the same as with SQL, which is record based, not object based, so the closest that you could come would be to use a join to allow doing just a single select to retrieve a single array having elements: recipes, guids, ingredients. This would repeat the recipe & guid for each ingredient, which you avoid by using nested objects. (See the answer below by @Fazal for an example of this.)

As another alternative, you could store the ingredients as a 'blob' field in the recipe table, but I don't believe that MySQL would allow you to create an Array field, so when retrieving the data, you would have to do a transform of the field into the array. And transform it from the Array before updating it into the table. Like: `storableData = JSON.stringify(arrayData)` and  `arrayData = JSON.parse(storableData)`

There are a few other things that I would suggest to help you improve the code though. (Yeah, I know, not really the question here):

1. Separate the routing functionality from data handling.
2. Also, separate data manipulation functionality from retrieval.
3. Use throw & .catch for creating and handling unsuccessful responses.

The separation of routing, data retrieval, data manipulation makes testing, debugging, and future comprehension easier as each function has a more atomic purpose.

Throwing/.catching unsuccessful process conditions makes it much simpler to have more comprehensive error processing by allowing you to put (most of the time) a single .catch in your router response handling (Hapi.js may even do this .catch for you???).

Also, see the other `.catch` and `.on('query-error'` that I added for logging errors. You may have a different logging mechanism you want to use rather than the console. I use Winston. And note that `.on('query-error'` is NOT a .catch. There will still be an Error() that is thrown, and must be handled somewhere, this will just give you good info about the failure close to the source.

(Sorry, the below code is untested)

```
path: '/recipes',
method: 'GET',
handler: (req, res) => {
        return getRecipeNIngredients()
            .then((recipes) => {
                res({
                    count: recipes.length,
                    data: recipes
                });
            })
            .catch((ex) => {
                res({
                    error: true,
                    errMessage: ex.message
                });
            });
};

    function getRecipeNIngredients() {
        let recipes = null;
        return getRecipes()
            .then((recipeList) => {
                recipes = recipeList;
                const recipeGuids = recipes.map(recipe => recipe.guid);
                recipes.forEach(r => r.ingredients = []);
                return getIngredients(recipeGuids);
            })
            .then((ingredients) => {
                recipes.forEach(r => {
                    ingredients.forEach(i => {
                        if (i.recipe === r.guid) {
                            r.ingredients.push(i);
                        }
                    });
                });
                return recipes;
            })
            .catch((ex) => {
                console.log(".getRecipeNIngredients ERROR ex:",ex); // log and rethrow error.
                throw ex;
            });
    };

    function getRecipes() {
        return Knex.from('recipes')
            // .innerJoin('ingredients', 'recipes.guid', 'ingredients.recipe')
            .select()
            .orderBy('rating', 'desc')
            .limit(10)
            .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
                console.log("KNEX getRecipes query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
            })
            .then((recipes) => {
                if (!recipes || recipes.length === 0) {
                    throw new Error('no recipes found')
                }
            })
    };
    function getIngredients(recipeGuids) {
        return Knex.from('ingredients')
            .whereIn('recipe', recipeGuids)
            .select()
            .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
                console.log("KNEX getIngredients query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
            })
    };
```

I hope this is Useful!
Gary.

Answer (score 2):

I created a library that return nested object even it has types for typescript

[Nested Knex](https://github.com/mohaalak/nested-knex)

```js
import * as n from 'nested-knex';

n.array(
  n.type({
    id: n.number("recipe.id", { id: true }),
    title: n.string("recipe.title"),
    ingredients: n.array(
      n.type({
        id: n.number("ingredients.id", { id: true }),
        title: n.string("ingredients.title")
      })
    )
  })
)
  .withQuery(
    knex
      .from("recipes")
      .innerJoin("ingredients", "recipes.guid", "ingredients.recipe")
      .select()
      .orderBy("rating", "desc")
      .limit(10)
  )
  .then(recipes => {});
```

so recipes even have types

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid nest query. Just use subquery as-

```
knex.select('*')
  .from(function () {
    this.select('*').from('recipes').limit(10).as('recipes'); // limit here
  })
  .leftJoin('ingredients', 'ingredients.recipe_id', 'recipes.guid')
  .then((rec) => {
    console.log(rec);
  })
```

see.. just few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated with knex that it does not support relationships, a model that allows nested objects which makes it easy to visualise data. I was almost about to switch to MongoDB until I came across this solution.

```
const recipes = await knex
    .select(
      "recipes.*",
      knex.raw(`to_json(ingredients.*) as "ingredient"`)
    )
    .from("recipes")
    .innerJoin(
      "ingredients",
      "recipes.id",
      "ingredients.recipeId"
    )
    .where({
      recipeId: recipeId,
    })

// This is the price you pay for using the query builder.
// I am still yet to convert this into a reusable function, that can create nested objects with 3 table joins.
  const final = recipes.reduce((result, row) => {
    let { ingredient, ...remainingProps } = row;
    result[row.id] = result[row.id] || {
      ...remainingProps,
      ingredients: [],
    };

    result[row.id].ingredients.push(ingredient);
    return result;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(final);
```

What did I learn?

1. Your ultimate goal is assumably to protect the database from lots of queries. It is almost guaranteed that a join query will outperform, multiple queries or subqueries for that matter. Therefore be careful about the approach you choose.
2. When selecting all columns from both tables, Postgres will ignore common fields. Therefore, I would suggest renaming the `id` field specifically so that you do not confuse which id field is it.
3. You will have to repeat the reduce function for every join query you write. Interestingly adhering to join queries, makes your queries much more readable and also allows you to move to ORMs in the future just in case.