# How to fetch rows related to the table I'm querying using Knex

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I'm facing an issue with my program. If you could please provide a solution or refer me to the right source it would be great.

I'm going to explain my problem with an example.

Lets say I want to get a post from my database and the result looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Post 1",
    "author_id": 1
}
```

My goal is to include within the result the details of the author. So the response would look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Post 1",
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Danny DeVito"
    }
}
```

I could currently achieve this with some code I wrote using a transaction. Is there a way to do this with an internal Knex function? If so, please provide an example. If not, is a transaction the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could `join` those two tables (`posts` and `authors`) and then map flat results to nested structure.
But, if you need to retrieve just one record - performing two SQL-queries (one for `post` and one for the related `author`) is ok too.

Comment: I realize this but I'm looking for something like Laravel's eager loading

Comment: knex is not an ORM, it's a query builder. So, you can't do this.

Comment: If you need this kind of functionality you might consider using ORM instead (e.g.[sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize), [objection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I found the following:

> Short answer: No.
>
> With Knex, you can retrieve data the same as with SQL, which is record
>   based, not object based

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522481/9919938)

However, after a bit of digging I found a package that can achieve something similar to Laravel's eager loading. It is called [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) and it allows me to keep my Knex.js migrations

Answer (score -1):

U have to use an ORM for that eg prisma or objection.js